# Proposition for canonical Q&A

Tags: discussion

As part of some hobby research I've acquired a lot of information about potentially terraforming the planet Venus. Recently there has been some exciting research, and the scattered [questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14050/how-to-render-venus-semi-habitable) [related](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25802/could-we-move-and-terraform-the-planet-venus) [to](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12303/building-a-base-on-the-surface-of-a-planet-like-venus) this issue have received vague and unfulfilling answers.
The idea then would be to create a canonical hard science q&a, where I give a first answer where I summarize the total understanding to this date (probably several a4's), which can be updated with new answers as more research comes to light.

Would this be a good idea for me to write?

Comment: If you write it you will receive DVs for self answering.

Comment: As @AndreiROM said you might be better writing for the blog.

Comment: I would give other people a chance to see and answer before picking my post as the answer.

Comment: @AndreiROM I'm still getting used to WB being run rather differently than othe SE sites.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking and self-answering a question.  Assuming the quality is good (the question is detailed enough that others *could* answer, for example), I don't see why that would be downvote-worthy.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do this if you want to use it as a sort of repository of information, but keep in mind that it's not really the format that WB was meant to take.

The idea here is to ask very pointed, well framed questions, and that the community answer.

If you self answer there's a good chance that people won't take it well. Also, there will be other answers, which might contradict of criticize some aspect of your own opinions. This is all allowed, and makes sense for WB, but will not serve your purpose of simply stating your knowledge.

What you want to accomplish is essentially writing a Wiki entry for terraforming Venus. A better approach might be to create a WB Meta post with this purpose and just link it in questions which require that sort of information, or maybe join chat and talk to some of our long term members about writing a blog article about it.

Comment: I'm all for contrarion opinions and discussion, and I didn't mean it as an oppertunity to show off (then I'd just go to wikipedia). I must say I'm a bit dissapointed that Q&A's are discouraged, I'm most active in the mathematica. forums, where they are encouraged and some of the best posts are Q&A's.

Answer (score 1):

From [Can I answer my own question?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) in the help center:

> Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

However, the question still has to meet the site's rules for questions: complete, not too broad/opinion-based/etc, on-topic.  I don't know enough about teraforming Venus to know whether that's logically one question or several.  But if you can make a properly-scoped canonical question on this topic, please feel free to do so.

If you intend for the community to maintain your answer, you should mark it as Community Wiki.  But you might be better off just offering your answer as one of possibly several.